# Why isn't Powershell clearing?

Tags: c#, powershell, office365, runspace

So, I'm having an issue getting my function to produce it's own data after the second time I run it. The first time I produce the GetUsers command, provided my username and password is right, it'll return an arraylist with my users. If I run it again, no matter what username or password I use, it'll return the same users. I'm sure my code is quite the mess, but I've been messing with it trying to get it to clear.

As for a little background, I consider myself a novice programmer so the problem very well could be something really basic.

Thanks!

```
 public ArrayList GetUsers(string user, string pass)
        {
            InitialSessionState iss = InitialSessionState.CreateDefault();

            iss.ImportPSModule(new[] { "MSOnline" });
            using (Runspace myRunSpace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(iss))
            {
              myRunSpace.Open();
              using (System.Management.Automation.PowerShell powershell = System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.Create())
              {
                  ArrayList available_users = new ArrayList();

                  //create Powershell runspace

                  powershell.Runspace = myRunSpace;

                  Command connect = new Command("Connect-MsolService");
                  System.Security.SecureString secureString = new System.Security.SecureString();
                  string myPassword = pass;
                  foreach (char c in myPassword)
                      secureString.AppendChar(c);

                  connect.Parameters.Add("Credential", new PSCredential(user, secureString));
                  powershell.Commands.AddCommand(connect);

                  Collection<PSObject> results = null;
                  results = powershell.Invoke();
                  powershell.Commands.Clear();

                  Command getuser = new Command("Get-MsolUser");
                  powershell.Commands.AddCommand(getuser);
                  results = null;

                  powershell.Stop();

                  results = powershell.Invoke();

                  foreach (PSObject item in results)
                  {
                      string userprincipalname = item.Properties["UserPrincipalName"].Value as string;
                      available_users.Add(userprincipalname);
                  }

                  powershell.Dispose();
                  myRunSpace.Dispose();

                  powershell.Runspace.Dispose();
                  powershell.Runspace.Close();
                  myRunSpace.Close();
                  return available_users;
              }
            }
        }
```

Comment: any final solution with full source code about it ?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried explicitly deleting or nulling the available_users type? I don't think it would be necessary, but...